# Failing XPath on xsl:variable with XML fragment

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

I must be missing something very basic. I want to look up a key from a transformed XML document in XML fragment stored in `xsl:variable`. Here's a minimal example:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<code>A</code>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:variable name="mappings">
        <mapping key="A">Amy</mapping>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="code">
        <xsl:value-of select="$mappings/mapping[@key = text()]"/> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transforming this XML document with the XSL stylesheet produces empty result. It seems that the comparison `@key = text()` is wrong, because when I use `<xsl:value-of select="$mappings/mapping[@key = 'A']"/>`, it retrieves the expected value (i.e. "Amy"). What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:template match="code">
    <xsl:value-of select="$mappings/mapping[@key = current()]"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation why this works? I can see now that it's likely due to the variable context, in which the XPath expression is evaluated.

Comment: @jindrichm `[@key = text()]` is comparing the `key` attribute of the mapping element against the text node child(ren) _of the same mapping element_.  The `current()` function escapes from the predicate and returns you the node that would be `.` outside the `value-of` (i.e. the `code`).

Answer (score 0):

With an intermediate variable, it works properly :

```
<xsl:template match="code">
    <xsl:variable name="keyval" select="./text()" />
    <out>
       <xsl:value-of select="$mappings/mapping[@key = $keyval]"/>
    </out>
</xsl:template>
```